# unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: rubymine

For 2 days i have been fighting with this problem. and could not get a solution
 link to my project files:

https://github.com/gitamsinghkaystha/streamingtestframework.git

ruby version:1.8
rubymine 4

Comment: And the error i m getting is C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 4.0.3\rb\testing\runner\tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb"
Testing started at 6:04 PM ...
Work directory: C:/rubygems/test/GaanaTest}
Loading files.... 
=========================================
 
0 files were loaded.
=========================================
Running tests...

Process finished with exit code 0